# Space of polynomials as a continuous image of F-space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}[a,b]$. Is there any norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $X$ s.th. $X$ is a continuous image of some $F$-space. ($F$-space means that there exists complete metric s.th. $d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)$) ?

My idea is use fact that there is no complete norm on $X$. I tried to consider $A:=Y/\ker\varphi$, where $\varphi:Y\rightarrow X$ is a continuous map from some $F$-space $Y$. Then $A$ is also $F$-space and I tried to use homomorphism theorem. Is it good idea or is there any simpler way to do it ?

Comment: Notation query :What is R[a,b] ?

Comment: Space of real polynomials of two variables : $a$ and $b$.

Comment: ok. So which topology or metric or norm are you putting on R[a,b]?

Comment: It is a question that is there any norm on $X$ s.th. it is continuous image of some $F$-space. So, I tried to show that there is no such norm. I suppose that such a norm exists, take topology given by this norm, and try to obtain a contradiction.